# Add values between two dates in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

So I've already found this question answered several times around here but for some reason, despite essentially copy and pasting the answers it still doesn't work for me.

I'm trying to add everything in a column (Americas!B:B) if the values in a date column are between two dates, so far I've tried this:

```
=SUMIFS(Americas!B:B,Americas!A:A,">="&$B$13,Americas!A:A,"<="&$B$14)
```

The sum would be happening on a different sheet (not the Americas sheet), and B13 and B14 are the start and end dates, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is valid. Try perhaps:

```
=SUMIFS(Americas!B1:B; Americas!A1:A; ">=" & $B$13; 
                       Americas!A1:A; "<=" & $B$14)
```